# Python - Mapping Two Lists (of Different Sizes)?

Tags: python, list

Let's say for example, I have the following two lists:

```
name = ["Joe Harris", "Susie Carmike"]
method = ["Lab"]
```

How can I map these two lists to where the output would be below? Or is there a better way other than lists in Python to map elements of different size to get such an output?

```
name           method

Joe Harris     Lab

Susie Carmike  Lab
```

Comment: map onto what? lets say  you have names `[a,b,c]` and methods `[a,b]` what output then? [ask]

Comment: If your data is static then you can also use tuple instead of lists which will require less processing time.

Comment: Is your desire to actually print the output you showed? Or do you want to turn it into a dictionary or something? Or something more complex like a pandas data frame?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) like below:

```
import itertools

name = ["Joe Harris", "Susie Carmike"]
method = ["Lab"]

somelists = [name] + [method]
for element in itertools.product(*somelists):
    print(element)
```

Output:

```
('Joe Harris', 'Lab')
('Susie Carmike', 'Lab')
```

Or:

```
>>> list(itertools.product(*somelists))
[('Joe Harris', 'Lab'), ('Susie Carmike', 'Lab')]
```

**For creating DataFrame try this:**

```
data = list(itertools.product(*somelists))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'method'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            name method
0     Joe Harris    Lab
1  Susie Carmike    Lab
```

**You can use this method for `multi list` like below:**

```
import itertools

name = ["Joe Harris", "Susie Carmike", "Joe Harris2"]
method = ["Lab", 'Lab2']
approach = ['app1', 'app2']

somelists = [name] + [method] + [approach]

list(itertools.product(*somelists))
```

Output:

```
[('Joe Harris', 'Lab', 'app1'),
 ('Joe Harris', 'Lab', 'app2'),
 ('Joe Harris', 'Lab2', 'app1'),
 ('Joe Harris', 'Lab2', 'app2'),
 ('Susie Carmike', 'Lab', 'app1'),
 ('Susie Carmike', 'Lab', 'app2'),
 ('Susie Carmike', 'Lab2', 'app1'),
 ('Susie Carmike', 'Lab2', 'app2'),
 ('Joe Harris2', 'Lab', 'app1'),
 ('Joe Harris2', 'Lab', 'app2'),
 ('Joe Harris2', 'Lab2', 'app1'),
 ('Joe Harris2', 'Lab2', 'app2')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `itertools.cycle`:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> list(zip(name, cycle(method)))
[('Joe Harris', 'Lab'), ('Susie Carmike', 'Lab')]
>>>
```

Comment: This assumes `len(method) <= len(names) ` it is unclear if this information is available to OP.